# (SFTP)how to have /var/www writable permission when set ChrootDirectory /var/www

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

ChrootDirectory  is tricky > <

As I google for it and found the ChrootDirectory setting explanation
(http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP)

It say " Depending on the opensshd version this may not be usable since some versions require that the chroot-target directory and all parent directories are owned by root and not writeable by any others. "

so in this explanation when I set like this :

`drwxr-sr-x  3 root sftp     4096 Mar  9 15:14 www`

If I set `root:root` or  `root:sftp` (chmod is 755) it can use sftp to connect to my /var/www but it don't have writable/deletable  permission.

but set www to `webmaster:sftp` or `chmod is 775`  can't connect

and this is my user that I want it to control /var/www (It's in the sftp group):

```
webmaster:x:1001:1001::/var/www:/bin/false
```

I set this bottom in my sshd_config :

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group sftp
X11Forwarding no
ChrootDirectory /var/www
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

change mod to 775 can't connect >"<

so how can I resolve this problem?

I want my group sftp can have chmod 775 in the /var/www . 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a catch-22 situation, but I think I have a way around it.

I recommend not using /var/www to host websites.  I treat this directory as system default that is only used if someone visits the server using a servername that doesn't match a vhost.

Instead, host sites in /srv/web, which conforms to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).
Each site directory (e.g. /srv/web/site1) has the following subdirectories:

```
htdocs
config
lib
logs
```

Set your vhost's DocumentRoot to /srv/web/site1/htdocs and use the other directories for things that don't need to be web-accessible.  Then you can make htdocs (and other subdirectories, if necessary) group-writable.  Chroot your sftp to /srv/web/site1 and tell people to upload to the htdocs directory.